# Bluetooth pairing without GUI

Tags: linux, shell, bluetooth, rfcomm, bluez

I need to use a USB Bluetooth dongle on a linux server.
Actually it works and I can discover other bluetooth devices, but if I try to connect with one of them (with `rfcomm`) it says `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused`.

I think that the problem is the pairing, because when I type the same command on desktop systems, it asks the passkey to me, in a dialog window (not in the terminal).
So the question is: how can I pair a device without a desktop environment?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command works for me:

```
echo [PIN] | bluez-simple-agent hci0 [BT_MAC_ADDRESS]
```

Comment: when I run your commend I get "Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists"

Comment: Me too, any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately `bluez-simple-agent` has been removed from recent Bluez versions, so this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your device is already paired, then to request pairing again, commands as below. Or else error mesage as *Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists*

   ```
   To remove pairing: bluez-test-device remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
   To pair again    : bluez-simple-agent hci0  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```
2. If you happen to have than 1 bluetooth hardware and would like to use second one, use `hciconfig` to find adapter name and then use that name in place of `hci#`. Command as below

   ```
   bluez-simple-agent hci# XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```

Comment: Note to those who land on this thread via a web search and wonder about "command not found" errors: unfortunately `bluez-simple-agent` has been removed from recent Bluez versions, so this no longer works.